# multiple buttons with one text area

Tags: css, button

I am just starting CSS and I do not know much about it that is why I am asking for help.

I would like to have 3 buttons with only one text area (not editable) that changes when I click on a button. As displayed on my screenshot, after clicking on 1, I have the text bla bla bla displayed. If I click on the button 2, I would like to have blo blo blo that replaces bla bla bla.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a great project. What's your question?

Comment: `I want to have`... is not a question

Comment: Sorry Nick, I wrote it a bit too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example done with Javascript. (pass different parameteres according to which button was clicked)

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gHb2u/1/

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var changeText = function(buttonId){
    var label = document.getElementById('label');
    if (buttonId == 1){
        label.innerHTML = "1";
    }
    else if (buttonId == 2){
     label.innerHTML = "2";
    }
    else{
     label.innerHTML = "3";
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="changeText(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="changeText(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="changeText(3)">3</button>

<label id="label">Text</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by using jQuery

**SCRIPT :**

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var b= this.id;
    var txt=$("#txt");
    if(b==="b1")
        txt.val("bla bla bla");
    else if(b==="b2")
        txt.val("blo blo blo");
    else if(b==="b3")
        txt.val("ble ble ble");
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<textarea id="txt">bla bla bla</textarea>
<button id="b1">1</button>
<button id="b2">2</button>
<button id="b3">3</button>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/gkm2Q/)